# How-to Replace or Modify Last Element of each Sub-list

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I hope everyone had a great start to the New Year!

I want to create a `NumberLinePlot`. Naturally, I have tried to utilise `NumberLinePlot`, but it did not serve my purpose as the duplicate values would present themselves as a single point.

1. I want to stack duplicate values;
2. and I want to use `Callout` to label data points in the plot. However, if there are duplicate entries, I only want the last point to have the `Callout`.

Here is where I am at this moment in time. I was wondering if somebody could provide advice on how-to "wolframify" the code and achieve the desired outcome. Bonus points for "asthetics"

```
data = Split @ { 1000, 5000, 5000, 5000, 4000, 3344, 2500 };

Flatten[Map[ Table[{First @  # , i}, {i, Length @ #}] &, data], 1] // 
 ListPlot[#, Axes -> {True, False}, AspectRatio -> .2] &

Map[Table[ {First @ #, i}, { i, Length @ # }] &, data] // 
  Map[ Callout[Last @ #, ToString @ First[#[[1]]], Above] &, #] & // 
  ListPlot[#, Axes -> {True, False}, AspectRatio -> .2] &
```

[image: points]

[image: labels]

Here is the input and output specification...

```
(* input *)
{ 1000, 5000, 5000, 5000, 4000, 3344, 2500, 2500 }

(* output *)
{ 
   Callout[{1000, 1}, 1000, Above] , 
   {5000, 1}, {5000, 2}, Callout[{5000, 3}, 5000, Above], 
   Callout[{4000, 1}, 4000, Above], 
   Callout[{3344, 1}, 3344, Above], 
   {2500, 1}, Callout[{2500, 2}, 2500, Above] 
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use[`SplitBy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SplitBy.html), [`MapIndexed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapIndexed.html), and [`MapAt`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapAt.html).

With

```
data = {1000, 5000, 5000, 5000, 4000, 3344, 2500, 2500}
```

then

```
ListPlot[
 Flatten[
  MapAt[Callout[#, First@#, Above] &, -1] /@
   MapIndexed[Flatten[{##}] &] /@
    SplitBy[data, Identity]
  , 1
  ]
 , Axes -> {True, False}
 , AspectRatio -> .2
 ]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

1. `SplitBy` [`Identity`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Identity.html) (could also use `#&`) to get the runs of values.
2. Then `MapIndexed` each value of each run with its position.
3. Finally, `MapAt` the last value in each indexed run the [`Callout`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Callout.html).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

```
data = {1000, 5000, 5000, 5000, 4000, 3344, 2500, 2500};
pts = Table[{First@#, i}, {i, 1, Length@#}]~
      Join~{Callout[{First@#, Length@#}, First@#, Above]} & /@ 
      Split@data // Catenate;

ListPlot[pts, Axes -> {True, False}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 4):

A way to add `Callout` labels to `NumberLinePlot`: Pre-process input data to add `Tooltip`s and post-process `NumberLinePlot` output to replace tooltips with callout labels:

```
raggedTranspose = Join[## & @@ Map[List, #, {-1}], 2] &;

addTooltips = MapAt[List @* Tooltip, #, {All, -1}] &;

preProcess = ReplaceAll[Tooltip -> Tooltip @* First] @* raggedTranspose @*  addTooltips; 

postProcess = ReplaceAll[Tooltip -> 
     ({#, First[ListPlot[{Callout[#[[1, 1]], #2, Above]}, PlotStyle -> None]]} &)];

numberLinePlotWithCallouts = postProcess @ NumberLinePlot[preProcess @ #, ##2] &;
```

***Example:***

```
data = Split @ {1000, 5000, 5000, 5000, 4000, 3344, 2500, 2500};

numberLinePlotWithCallouts[data, 
 ImageSize -> 500, 
 ImagePadding -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Automatic, 20}}, 
 PlotStyle -> AbsolutePointSize[7]]
```

[image]